# Stream iTunes university videos with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios

I'm looking for a method which permit to me to stream iTunes university videos with MPMoviePlayerController.

I have already try to find an answer through a lot of requests on google, without succes!

So, I would like to know if it's possible, and if yes how?

Thanks